# Remove N Character (non Unicode support)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am using EF 4.1 Code First.
EF generates a query for the IN clause is :

```
SELECT Column1
FROM Table1 
WHERE Column1 IN (N'ABC',N'XYZ', N'DEF')
```

The IN clause is generated by using List.Contains() method.

Is there any way so that I can remove unicode values (N character) from in clause ?
So the query should look like

```
SELECT Column1
FROM Table1 
WHERE Column1 IN ('ABC','XYZ', 'DEF')
```

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Note: I have specified all the column type as mentioned in DB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF 4 produces UNICODE string constans in SQL where the column type is varchar. How to avoid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828621/ef-4-produces-unicode-string-constans-in-sql-where-the-column-type-is-varchar-h) Summary: it was a bug in EF 4.1 and it has been fixed in a later version (no idea which one though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to convert list of unicode strings into Non unicode strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but..

1. Check Column1 Type on your EF model (Unicode property) to be set to
   false.
2. Be sure do not apply any string functions like "Trim" or smthng similar. This will convert your db value in a unicode string.